# Rspec error when using expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I'm getting the error:

> The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`.

from my rspec which is this:

```
expect { click_button submit }.to.change(User, :count).by(1)
```

How can I rephrase the rspec so it passes?

Comment: Try expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I was pulling my hair out over that one.

Comment: So that this doesn't remain open, you should answer your own question or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are chaining your test.

`expect { click_button submit }.to.change(User, :count).by(1)`

Should become (note the space between `to` and `change`.

`expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)`